# How can I order the bars in my histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**I've looked at, for example, ["Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) and ["How to reorder the groups in a grouped bar-chart [duplicate]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504876/how-to-reorder-the-groups-in-a-grouped-bar-chart). But I haven't been able to adapt those to my problem.**

I'm trying to make a very basic histogram, with the bars being the number of models in each class and being ordered by that number:

```
library(ggplot2)

mpg %>%
  ggplot +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(
    x = reorder(class, count)
  ))
```

I can make the unordered version work:

```
mpg %>%
  ggplot +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(
    x = class
  ))
```

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to order that factor by count?

Comment: This is a bar chart, not a histogram. A histogram is a specific type of chart that shows a continuous distribution broken into bins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `forcats` package:

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(fct_infreq(class))) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you. Can I ask how to add the count labels, or should I make that a separate question? (I find working with counts in ggplot really tricky.)

Comment: No worries. I had to make a duplicate dataframe called `mpg2` cause I used `data.table` and it doesn't let me edit `mpg` directly but here's the code. Use data.table to add counts: `setDT(mpg2)[, counts := .N, by = class]` and then add the following layer to your ggplot: `stat_summary(aes(label = counts, y = 1.05*max(counts)), geom = "text")`