# Reorder geom_bar based on sort of one of the fill variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

with data

```
dat <- 
    structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                     .Label = c("alwaysFirst", "last"), 
                                     class = "factor"), 
                   rsk = structure(c(3L,1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), 
                                   .Label = c("beginning", "middle", "startsWithS", "zed"), 
                                   class = "factor"), 
                   prop = c(0.47, 0.38, 0.15, 0.54, 0.14, 0.78, 0.64, 0.36)), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I can group and reorder a `geom_bar()` with

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = rsk %>% fct_reorder(-prop), y = prop, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

This reorders based on the default `.fun = median` in the `fct_reorder()` statement. This is great, but when I'm also dealing with a `fill` in `aes()`, I'd like to force the `fct_reorder` to use *only* one of the `fill` values to reorder the plot.

In other words, for the data above, I'd like the plot to be in x-axis order of: `zed`, `startsWithS`, `beginning`, `middle`, the descending order based upon the ordering of the `prop` values where `group == "alwaysFirst"`. I can hardcode the reordering of the values with the `levels` argument of `factor()` ([as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504876/how-to-reorder-the-groups-in-a-grouped-bar-chart)) but I'd rather let `ggplot` do it, if possible, especially as this could change with different groups.

How can I force `ggplot` to reorder the `x` values based only on one of the groups in the `fill` argument?

Comment: You could try `fct_reorder2` to reorder by both the category and the value. I find it pretty tricky to get exactly right, so you might need to mess around with it. I'd also recommend doing that rearranging *before* you try to plot so you can write it more clearly and verify it. You can then still pipe the rearranged data into `ggplot` the way you have here

Comment: Also, this question might help if I'm imagining what you want correctly https://stackoverflow.com/q/31955729/5325862

Comment: @camille Thanks. I ended up `arrange()`ing the dataframe by `group, desc(prop)` then `mutate(rsk = rsk %>% factor(levels = unique(rsk)))` to get the appropriate order of `rsk` along the x-axis. I need to explore `fct_reorder2()` more. I've used `fct_reorder()` quite bit but never it's cousin.